# windows form controls are not visible in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

in my application i need to include windows form controls but the controls are not visible
in wpf Window ....How to make them visible

Xaml:

```
    <WindowsFormsHost Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="266,274,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" >
        <wf:Button BackColor="Blue" Margin="266,274,0,0" Width="100" Height="100" Text="Click Me" Click="Button_Clik"></wf:Button>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

C#:

```
    private void Button_Clik(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hi");
    }
```

Comment: I am wondering why you would need those controls (`Button`) unless not available or creatable in WPF?

Comment: Button is just an example .....My Actual need is to use PictureBox and Chart controls in wpf

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, your `WindowsFormsHost` is 200units wide, but you move the child in the `WindowsFormsHost` via `Margin` to 266. Same for the height. So you can't see it, because its not in the viewport anymore. Also don't layout pixel/unit wise using margins. Thats a bad habit the visual studio designer does. If you really really need xy positions, use a `Canvas`.